# add new column to dataframe with values matching the keys with existing column in dataframe in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

fairly new to python and pandas/numpy. I have a data frame and a dictionary. I need to add a new column in the data frame where the values would be the values from dictionary for the matching dictionary keys with the existing column in data frame. and have empty string for non matching values.

|  | Name | Fonder | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | company1 | person1 | 1999 |
| 1 | company2 | person2 | 2000 |
| 2 | company3 | person3 | 2001 |
| 3 | company4 | person4 | 2002 |
| 4 | company5 | person5 | 2003 |

```
col_dict = {'company2': 'abc', 'company4': 'xyz',}
```

I want the following

|  | Name | Fonder | Year | new_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | company1 | person1 | 1999 |  |
| 1 | company2 | person2 | 2000 | abc |
| 2 | company3 | person3 | 2001 |  |
| 3 | company4 | person4 | 2002 | xyz |
| 4 | company5 | person5 | 2003 |  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['new_col'] = df['Name'].map(col_dict).fillna('')
print(df)

# Output
       Name   Fonder  Year new_col
0  company1  person1  1999        
1  company2  person2  2000     abc
2  company3  person3  2001        
3  company4  person4  2002     xyz
4  company5  person5  2003
```